# Undo git last commit push

Tags: git, github, commit

I wanted to undo the last changes I made to a file both on my local repo and the repo on Github. (`origin`)

Could someone please point me to a post/blog of doing it.

Here are the steps I did for committing the changes:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "changed header"
git push origin master
```

How can I undo the last changes, both on my local repo and origin.

Answer (score 5):

1. do a hard reset to throw out the bad commit:

   ```
   git reset --hard HEAD^
   ```
2. force push

   ```
   git push -f origin master
   ```

Note: the `reset --hard` is going to throw out any changes you made in the most recent commit, unless you still have a branch someplace maintaining a reference to that commit.  The previous `HEAD` will still be in the reflog, though, in case you need it back in the near term.  To be very safe, make a backup branch first:

```
git branch backup master
```

If everything goes well, you can `git branch -D backup` later on.

Comment: This should come with a big, red warning about losing data.

Comment: It seems like that's what the OP wants, though.  I'll add something to be clear.

Comment: @MattBall: Losing data? I just changed a single line in this commit that I want to undo. I hope that line reverts back to the previous state, without anything else happening.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Currently, I haven't done anything to my repo. `git status gives a nothing to commit message`. I guess I'm safe?

Comment: about the data loss: it does what the author asks for, but it is possible (and somewhat reasonable) that either the author or some future reader has a problem where they think "undoing a push" is the solution, when it is a bad solution or not a solution at all. the warning is there to stop them from doing this (possibly dangerous and annoying) accidentally. also: there should be another, slightly smaller warning about annoying collaborators.

Comment: @mnagel: Thanks for the tip. But, its my own repo: no collaborators. No one has pulled/cloned it. Therefore, I just want to make sure, whether it is safe or not? Also, will the repo become exactly like its  one-step-earlier state?

Comment: @Palak: it is safe if you are the only one using the repo (and you don't use multiple clones on different machines yourself). and yes, `master` will point to the unchanged `HEAD^` commit, and the erratic commit will simply be forgotten. so your branch will be exactly as it was before.

Comment: git reset will eventually generate problems. This should be used as a "workaround" and not as a "procedure". I think the best way is to use the opposite of the changes as @pgilmon explains.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm using Sourcetree and I have no idea how to do it there. Anyways, so this really saved my day. I'm working at two different companies and I pushed wrong commit message to the wrong company's project. This is actually good, cause I'm doing the projects solo. Thank you again. The #2 step is important. Otherwise you'll just revert to the last commit.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying already pushed commits or the history of remote branches is not recommended. If you do so, you would be potentially messing up other people's work, or at least making it more difficult for them to integrate their work back to the remote branch (`origin/master` in this case).

A way of undoing what you committed without playing with `origin/master`'s history is by creating a new commit that undoes what you previously did, and then pushing that new commit.

First, create a patch that contains the opposite of the changes you made in the last commit:

`git diff HEAD HEAD~1 > revert.patch`

By issuing that command you are telling Git to create a patch file that describes how to get to HEAD~1 from HEAD (i.e.: to the previous-to-last commit from the last commit).

Then, you apply that patch:

`git apply revert.patch`

That will apply that patch and modify the files in your working copy. You can delete the patch file now (`revert.patch`).

Now your working copy is reverted to the state previous to the last commit, but those changes are not into the Git repo yet. You must add and commit them. (Use `git gui` or `git add`/`git commit`, or whatever method you usually use to commit changes).

Once you new commit has been generated, just push it

`git push origin master`

Now you will have

```
A'  (master) - (origin/master)
|
B
|
A
```

Where `A'` is the new commit you generated, containing the same files as the commit you wanted to revert to (`A`)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to do `git revert HEAD`, `git push origin master` unless there is a good reason to use `reset`.